# Expected value of $e^{\alpha \sqrt{t-s} \ Z}$

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, moment-generating-function

How can I find the expected value of this:

$e^{\alpha \sqrt{t-s} \ Z}$, where Z is a standard normal random variable.

I know the moment generating function should help me with this, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Is this for a homework assignment?

Comment: @AdamO Not exactly.

Comment: Have you checked out the Wikipedia pages for moment-generating function and Normal distribution?

Comment: Write down the definition for the generating function.  How does it relate to what you want to calculate?

Comment: @P.Windridge I see it is the expectation of $e^{tZ}$ Can I just substitute my $\alpha \sqrt{t-s}$ for that $t$?

Comment: Let $Z$ be standard normal. Then $E[e^{cZ}] = e^{c^2/2}$. Set $c=\alpha\sqrt{t-s}$ to obtain the answer.

Comment: When you say "not exactly", could you be more precise about the source of the question?

Comment: @Roanne Yes, you can substitute one constant for an equivalent constant.